# How to apply custom styling on react-datepicker with css modules?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I am trying to apply custom styling on `react-datepicker` datepicker input. Using modules:

```
.custom-input {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 30px !important;
  border: 2px solid #cccccc !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  line-height: 26px !important;
}
```

And then I add the className to the datepicker:

```
 <DatePicker
      className={s["custom-input"]}/>
```

I created codesandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/clnd-datepicker-forked-h9ju59

Any idea why its not working, even with `!important` on?

[EDIT]
Codesandbox is fixed.

Comment: sandbox is not working for me, hence cant see the output. Could you please provide output ss and chrome browser element ss?

Comment: @Chandan fixed it, could you check again?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/clnd-datepicker-forked-m5imoi : use the class name directly in the datepicker. see your forked sandbox Alex.

Comment: @Chandan I dont see any changes, is it working? I dont see styles being applied at all

Answer (score 0):

Hello Alex : I took the code to my local vs code and updated the code a little bit which worked:
The only difference I code see here is instead of using s[""] you can use like :

```
import styles or <any name you would like to call it> from "./Datepicker.module.css"
```

and then call the `css class name` in the code like:

```
className ={styles.<cssClassName>}.
```

See my code ss: [image: VS Code Screenshot]

PS: I also found one strange thing about codesandbox is that it keeps complaining about .module.css file in typescript code file. hence my codesandbox that I sent earlier wasn't working well.

Comment: Oh so this is codesandbox issue only? Could be the case

Comment: do let me know if above code works fine for you, if yes, please mark it accepted.